# Dart/Flutter - summing maps and lists with duplicates

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a weekly report for a restaurant.  There is a firestore document summarizing each day, with data that looks (partially) like this:

**Day 1**
[image]
**Day 2**
[image]

I'll have different servers on each day.  The goal is to end up with a Map that I can use to display the report:

{ "mark": 325, "mary": 3675 }

So far I have a list of distinct servers, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I iterate over that list to create another list? Should I be folding? Or should I have gone in a different direction?

Thanks!

```
  buildTipList(List<ReservationSummary> rsList, context) {
    List servers = [];
    rsList.forEach((rs) {
      rs.tipsReceived.keys.forEach((key) => servers.add(key));
    });
    List distinctServers = servers.toSet().toList();
    ...
    ...
    return ListView.separated(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(distinctServers[index]),
            trailing: Text("???"),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
        itemCount: distinctServers.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier to do with a map.

```
buildTipList(List rsList, context) {
    Map tipMap = {};

    rsList.forEach((
      rs.tipsReceived.forEach((server, tip) {

       // ORIGINAL
       // if (tipMap.containsKey(server)) {
       //   tipMap[server] += tip;
       // } else {
       //   tipMap[server] = tip;
       // }

       // Randal Schwartz improvement:
        tipMap.update(
          server,
          (value) => value + tip,
          ifAbsent: () => tip,
        );

      });
    });
    
    return ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: tipMap.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        String key = tipMap.keys.elementAt(index);
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(key),
          trailing: Text("\$ ${tipMap[key]}"),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
    );
```

Comment: `        if (tipMap.containsKey(server)) {
          tipMap[server] += tip;
        } else {
          tipMap[server] = tip;
        }` is better written with Map.update, which can have an "if absent" component..

Comment: so `tipMap.update(server, (value) => value + tip, ifAbsent: tip);`? Seems cleaner thanks